# A strange multiplicative function

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function

I have a function that looks like
$$f_n(i) = \max\left(\left\lfloor \frac{i-n}{2} \right \rfloor + 1, 0\right)$$

and I would like to write it as a nice arithmetic function. To give an idea, another example where I can find a suitable answer is
$$g_n(i) = \max\left(i-n+1, 0\right)$$

where I get $g_n(i+n) = i+1 = \tau(p^{i})$.

But in the case of $f$ it would end with something like $\tau(p^{\lfloor i/2\rfloor})$, and... it does not seem very multiplicative, is it?

Comment: In order to write $f_n$ as multiplicative function, it should be multiplicative. Is it?

Comment: What do you understand under *nice*? $f_n(i)$ is already nice in this form - at least, it is explicit=)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Indeed it does not seem to be, however maybe is there a good decomposition of it, essentially as multiplicative/sum of multiplicative functions ? (I do not succeeded in trying to split the cases to getting rid of the division as well as the floor part...)